# Listening to one of two people talking at the same time

Tags: acoustics

Suppose a man and a woman are talking continuously and with the same volume. Can you choose to listen to one of them and yet understand what he/she is saying? According to my experience the answer is positive. I suppose we can distinguish the voice because the voices of them have different frequency range. Now here is my question: What if two men are talking at the same time, with an identical frequency range? Is my hypothesis true, that frequency is the only factor here?

Comment: Humans don't use a band-pass filter to ignore the secondary signal.

Comment: Try putting on two recordings of the same person talking and see if you can still focus on one or the other. My experience is that I can, which indicates there's more going on than just frequency range.

Comment: google "cocktail party effect"

Comment: It is a very interesting question but it's not really about physics as currently written

Comment: Human has two ears and the brain is able to extract information from the time difference on which sound arrives to the left and right ear. I know what I’m talking about because I need and wear a little ear loudspeaker in my left ear only. The noise level I feel with and without the device is the same for me, but the extraction of different voices is phenomenal different. But as @Floris says, it is not really about physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my hypothesis true, that frequency is the only factor here?

No.

As mentioned in some comments (one of which probably could have become an answer), there are things beyond frequency that we use to differentiate conversations/noise.

As f5r5e5d rightly pointed out in the comments, see the [cocktail party effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect) for some context about the situation.  For more depth on the mechanism (quite a bit of depth for wikipedia actually) you could start reading about [sound localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization). (and I'm sure there are plenty of good sources on this; but wikipedia is alright if you just want a summary/feel for it)

To summarize from a *physical* perspective, you have to consider how human hearing is set up.  The sound doesn't hit a singular location to be processed; we have two ears which can each individually pick up sounds.  Due to this difference in position, depending on the location of the source, each ear will pick up the signal at different times and even different intensities (due to interference and/or the shape of the ear filtering sound from some directions).

Our brains are really good at processing information that we don't even consciously consider.  Assuming the two men weren't talking from the exact same position, it should be entirely possible to differentiate the two voices.  The further apart the two men are from each other (as long as the distance between talkers and the listener hasn't changed), the easier it should be to tell them apart.

So basically, it's physically possible to differentiate two signals if you have two devices that are processing the signals.  That's especially true with ears, because each ear is also directionally oriented; giving even more cues for your brain to convert into a direction of the sound source.

How does the brain do this?  I don't know; nor is it really on topic for a physics site.  I'm sure that would be an interesting cognitive science question ([maybe already answered?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/do-we-only-hear-what-we-want-to-hear/6052#6052)).

Comment: While all these factors surely help, the brain is fully capable of understanding one of  two conversations originating from the same source without any difference in signal acquisition. I just tried it using a recording of someone talking with a time offset recording of the same person both playing simultaneously from a single speaker. You can use the free software Audacity to reproduce it. I could switch at will between the two different speeches made by the same person and understand each. They have to be at about the same volume though.

Comment: That is probably because language has a certain structure and the brain probably hooks up to the part of the signal that has that structure and considers the rest as noise. That's pretty impressive though when you try it.